# initialise timezoneJS with JSON files

Tags: javascript, timezone

I'm working with timezone-js: https://github.com/mde/timezone-js. I have a list of predefined timezones I want to work with. So I pre-parsed JSON Data of those timezones.

But how exactly am I supposed to use this data?

```
var _tz = timezoneJS.timezone;
_tz.loadingScheme = _tz.loadingSchemes.MANUAL_LOAD;
_tz.loadZoneJSONData('/major_cities.json', true);
```

I can read the data, like here. But how am I supposed to use the `tz` variable to initialise timezoneJS?

I'm thinking that I'm supposed to do something like this first:

`timezoneJS.timezone.loadZoneDataFromObject(_tz);`

And then initialise it... And then initialise timezoneJS, but if I initialise now, I'll get an error that it can't find the default timezone: `Uncaught Error: Error retrieving "null/northamerica" zoneinfo files`, probably because I've supplied the json data.

Can I'd like to know what to do to use the json file, so I can create `timezoneJS.Date` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, tz_ is just a short cut which prevents writing timezoneJS.timezone in the subsequent lines.

Now, there are two options. If you have your file *major_cities.json* on the server and you want to initialize timezoneJS you just have to do what you wrote:

```
var _tz = timezoneJS.timezone;
_tz.loadingScheme = _tz.loadingSchemes.MANUAL_LOAD;
_tz.loadZoneJSONData('/major_cities.json', true);
```

and you're all set. The second option is that you have an object containing data from that file. In such case you should use *loadZoneDataFromObject* instead of *loadZoneJSONData*, namely:

```
var _tz = timezoneJS.timezone;
_tz.loadingScheme = _tz.loadingSchemes.MANUAL_LOAD;
_tz.loadZoneDataFromObject(majorCitiesObject);
```

After that, you should not try calling the init function, hence timezoneJS is already initialized by the loadZoneJSONData. If you want to create a date, just call new timezoneJS.Date(). The following lines should give you a hint:

```
var timezoneName = 'Europe/London';
var newDate = new timezoneJS.Date(timezoneName);
console.log(newDate.toString());
console.log(newDate.toISOString());
```

Result should be sth like:

```
2013-04-08 11:56:33
2013-04-08T10:56:33.019Z
```